# Is there a way to provide additional customization to the google classroom share popup

Tags: google-classroom

I'm currently trying to create a 'Share to Google Classroom' with some fields prefilled. I'm looking for a way to filter the 'Choose action' dropdown to just the 'Create assignment' and 'Make an announcement' options, as well as being able to prefill the due date after the user has selected 'Create assignment'.

I'm currently using the https://classroom.google.com/share link, and am looking to find out what query parameters it has. Currently the only parameters I know about are 'url', 'body', and 'title'. I haven't been able to find any documentation about this URLs query parameters, and have looked through all the classroom stack overflow posts, but haven't found anything talking about additional query parameters. Is this customization possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a function for customizing the Share to Google Classroom other than the given [public docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton#configuration) and there is no feature request for that. If it seems interesting, you can try filing a feature request for this. Hope this helps.